Use pct_change for DateTime (sub)Index along with group_by for multi-index data frame
Here is my sample data:
                     indicator1
company  date                  
company1 2015-01-01        97.0
         2016-01-01        55.0
         2017-01-01        47.0
         2018-01-01        68.0
         2019-01-01        65.0
company2 2015-01-01        22.0
         2016-01-01        40.0
         2017-01-01        22.0
         2018-01-01        12.0
         2019-01-01        86.0
company3 2015-01-01        47.0
         2016-01-01        28.0
         2017-01-01        91.0
         2018-01-01        63.0
         2018-05-01       123.0
         2019-01-01        57.0

I'm trying to calculate 1-year pct_chng this way:
df["pct_chng_3"] = df.groupby("company", group_keys=False)\
    .apply(lambda x: x['indicator1'].pct_change(periods = period, freq = 'Y'))

It works fine w/o the freq parameter (just does pct_change line-by_line), but as soon as I add freq = 'Y' I'm getting the error:
new_ax = index.shift(periods, freq)
NotImplementedError: This method is only implemented for DatetimeIndex, PeriodIndex and TimedeltaIndex; Got type MultiIndex

I presume that is caused by the fact that groupBy leaves the two-dimensional index in place, that confuses the "shift" method.
I can't figure out a nice workaround.

Use DateOffset for specify frequency, for avoid your error convert first level company to column by Series.reset_index, count pct_change and again recreate MultiIndex:
df1 = df.reset_index(level=0)

out = (df.join(df1.groupby("company", group_keys=False, sort=False)['indicator1']
                  .pct_change(freq=pd.DateOffset(years=1))
                  .to_frame('pct_chng_3')
                  .set_index(df1['company'], append=True).swaplevel()))
print (out)
                     indicator1  pct_chng_3
company  date                              
company1 2015-01-01        97.0         NaN
         2016-01-01        55.0   -0.432990
         2017-01-01        47.0   -0.145455
         2018-01-01        68.0    0.446809
         2019-01-01        65.0   -0.044118
company2 2015-01-01        22.0         NaN
         2016-01-01        40.0    0.818182
         2017-01-01        22.0   -0.450000
         2018-01-01        12.0   -0.454545
         2019-01-01        86.0    6.166667
company3 2015-01-01        47.0         NaN
         2016-01-01        28.0   -0.404255
         2017-01-01        91.0    2.250000
         2018-01-01        63.0   -0.307692
         2018-05-01       123.0         NaN
         2019-01-01        57.0   -0.095238

Another idea without MultiIndex output is create numpy array, in my opinion less safe:
df['pct_chng_3'] = (df.reset_index(level=0)
                      .groupby("company", group_keys=False, sort=False)['indicator1']
                      .pct_change(freq=pd.DateOffset(years=1)).to_numpy())
print (df)
                     indicator1  pct_chng_3
company  date                              
company1 2015-01-01        97.0         NaN
         2016-01-01        55.0   -0.432990
         2017-01-01        47.0   -0.145455
         2018-01-01        68.0    0.446809
         2019-01-01        65.0   -0.044118
company2 2015-01-01        22.0         NaN
         2016-01-01        40.0    0.818182
         2017-01-01        22.0   -0.450000
         2018-01-01        12.0   -0.454545
         2019-01-01        86.0    6.166667
company3 2015-01-01        47.0         NaN
         2016-01-01        28.0   -0.404255
         2017-01-01        91.0    2.250000
         2018-01-01        63.0   -0.307692
         2018-05-01       123.0         NaN
         2019-01-01        57.0   -0.095238 


Thanks! That worked! Resetting one level of the index lead me to another idea. Just added reset index before my previous version and re-create the index afterwards. But not very sure if that is a safe option

@Arseni - There is problem you need DatetimeIndex, so only .reset_index() not work here.
